# C# seeing if user entered text in the command line

Tags: c#, if-statement, user-input

I want the user to enter a question. They can type "A" and ask a question. If they type "S" then it will shake the list of answers. If they type "S" first before they enter a question then they will get an error message.

I'm having trouble with my if else statements. I can't seem to figure out if they enter a question before they shake.

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Main program!");
     Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball");
     Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
     Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
     Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
     Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
     Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
     Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball();
     string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

     public string userAnswer

     do
     {
        if (input == "S")
        {
            if (userAnswer != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Searching the Mystic Realms(RAM) for the answer");
            }
            else
            {
                //Call Method Shake()
            }
        }
        else if (input == "A") {
                userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (input == "G") {
               //Call Method GetAnswer()
        }
    } while (input != "E");
}
```

Magic8Ball.cs

```
public void Shake()
    {
        //picking the index of the answer to show the user
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(_answers.Count);
        randomString = _answers[index];
    }

    public string GetAnswer()
    {
        //using the index picked by shake to return the answer
        //return "";
        return randomString;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use a variable to store if they ever entered a question. And then just check if they did.

Comment: @stickybit I tried using userAnswer for this and they are all highlighted red for error in my statements.

Comment: That's why I put userAnswer != null

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your question. Anyway, declare it as a local variable not a member, which isn't allowed in methods. Remove the `public` and end the declaration with a semicolon. You also need to explicitly initialize it. Try: `string userAnswer = null;` instead of `public string userAnswer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that you didn't initialize `userAnswer` and this is why, when the user types **S** for the first time, the `userAnswer` variable has a random value which is, very likely, `!=null`.

The fix is easy: initialize `userAnswer` with `null`.

Comment: I tried changing it to = null. I'm still getting this error for my variable. CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.userAnswer' Magic8Ball-Console

Comment: Then declare it as `static` as well.